# Angular Web App Deployed to Prod in AWS Serverless fails to load icons Host failed to decode downloaded font

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, font-awesome, aws-serverless

In my styles.scss in my Angular app.

I import font-awesome like so...
@import "~font-awesome/css/font-awesome"; //Also as scss

Works fine locally, but once to deployed to AWS I get the console warning...
Failed to decode downloaded font: https://XXXXXXX.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/Prod/fontawesome-webfont.20fd1704ea223900efa9.woff2
and the icons don't display.

I have added the file types on the AWS Console in Binary Media Types font/woff etc etc.

I also have tried adding @font-face directly to the font types as per [Failed to decode downloaded font on lambda production app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58752602/failed-to-decode-downloaded-font-on-lambda-production-app)

However still no joy.

Any ideas??

Regards

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with angular-fontawesome.  It was super easy to implement, integrates well and renders rapidly and most importantly there were no issues when on a AWS Serverless Application.  Also you only load up the icons you use - no extra baggage.
https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome

Also a very handy Stackblitz to test icons...
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fontawesome-sample?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts